# Пунктуация плюс "предоставить" или "представить"?

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов

По пред(о)ставленной информации(,) с 2015 года по 2018 год составлены протоколы об адмправонарушениях…

Answer (score 0):

Предлог ***по*** лучше заменить на ***согласно***. Обособление *допускается, но лучше без запятой,* поскольку оборот стоит в начале предложения (подробнее смотрите [здесь](http://gramatik.ru/zapyatye-pri-konstruktsiyah-s-soglasno)).

Что касается причастия, то у глаголов *представить* и *пред**о**ставить,* от которых они образованы, разные смыслы. ***Представленная*** информация значит *фигурирующая, продемонстрированная в каком-то документе информация.* А вот словосочетание ***предоставить информацию*** стало модным недавно и, на мой взгляд, сугубо канцелярское. Означает оно *сказать какие-то сведения,* если я правильно понимаю. К сожалению, на таком языке любят говорить операторы в горячих линиях разных служб. Так что если и использовать это *"по пред**о**ставленной информации",* то обязательно надо указать, ***кем*** информация предоставлена.